I need a simple way to cut the face back off the rest of the mesh
When I first imported the model to start porting it for SFM, I made the mistake of joining all the separate mesh pieces together. This wouldn't have been a problem, if I didn't need the face to be separate, and now I have no way of unseparating it. I tried re-importing the separate face piece to use as a slice with the Bool Tool, but this didn't work. Does anyone have any advice or help, or am I doomed to start from scratch?


If you say you joined all the seperate meshes once, i assume the face was seperate as well. If you just joined the meshes but didn't merge the vertices, try to select the face with hovering over a part of the face and press L and then p>selection to seperate it again.
Else select the face vertices with the "C" select tool and press p>selection.
